# How remove files with confirmation in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-14.04

I need to know that flag set for eliminate files with confirmation.

I have used rm -rf folder, but It is wrong because remove files with no confirmation

Too try -i , but this delete file by file. I need to eliminate all the folder at once but with confirmation yes or not

```
fernando@fernando:~$ rm -rfi jquery/
rm: ¿descender al directorio «jquery»? (s/n)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rm -rI <folder>` will ask for confirmation, because the `-I` flag will prompt the user to confirm (only for the folder itself).

Comment: friend but I have a folder that contains files in its inside. How eliminate all the folder at once, not file by file

Answer (score 1):

```
rm -r
```

will work - rm asks for confirmation by default.

the -r flag is for recursive
the -f flag is for 'force' (i.e. don't ask for confirmation)

```
man rm
```

will give you lots of information

```
-f  Attempt to remove the files without prompting for confirmation, regardless of the file's
    permissions.  If the file does not exist, do not display a diagnostic message or modify
    the exit status to reflect an error.  
    The -f option overrides any previous -i options.
```